# HTML e CSS: colocando duas imagens lado a lado com legenda embaixo de cada uma no README do meu perfil do GitHub

Tags: css, html5, github, visual-studio-code, markdown

#### Contexto

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento web e estou estudando HTML, CSS e JS puros para front-end. Paralelamente, venho estudando Git para versionar meus projetos de estudo/estudo de caso. Resolvi criar um README para meu perfil no GitHub, pois vi algumas personalizações bem legais e estou querendo dar "minha cara" ao meu perfil, a fim de fazer contato e network com a galera de desenvolvimento web e análise de dados (duas áreas que venho estudando). Ainda, vi uma boa oportunidade de treinar um pouco de HTML incorporado ao Markdown.
Fiz praticamente todo o arquivo utilizando as tags "details" e "summary" para que a pessoa que for ler possa abrir e fechar cada setor de informação. Como um dos setores fala sobre minhas "paixões" e uma delas é a leitura, achei interessante (e mais "humano") adicionar o que estou lendo no momento. Assim, adicionei um setor para colocar os dois livros que estou lendo/estudando no momento. A ideia era colocar uma imagem de cada livro (portanto, duas imagens) e uma legenda abaixo de cada imagem com o capítulo que está sendo lido no momento (portanto, duas legendas). Pesquisei um pouco melhor sobre o uso da tag "img" e as boas práticas de inserção de imagens em arquivos Markdown e HTML, e cheguei à conclusão de que seria melhor adicionar as imagens com tags HTML. Para isso, utilizei as tags "figure", "img" e "figcaption".

#### O que escrevi

```
<details>
    <summary><strong>What am I reading now?</strong></summary>  
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content:space-between;">
            <figure style="text-align:center; flex:1;">
                <img src="src/book1.png" alt= "Summit Lake - Charles Donlea" width="200px"/>
                <figcaption styles="text-align: center;">Chapter 26</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure style="text-align:center; flex:1;">
                <img src="src/book2.png" alt= "Confident Data Skills - Kirill Eremenko" alt="Confident Data Skills" width="200px"/>
                <figcaption styles="text-align: center;">Chapter 2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>

</details>&nbsp;
```

#### Explicando o que fiz

Como podem notar, adicionei uma "div" porque concluí que seria melhor para estilizar o conteúdo na tela. Coloquei cada imagem para ter uma largura de 200 pixels e fiz uso de flexbox para tentar assentar as imagens na tela (mesmo tendo utilizado "block" e "inline-block" antes do "flex").

#### Problema

Confesso que apanhei um pouco para conseguir colocar as imagens lado a lado e as legendas logo abaixo delas, mas no final entendi o que eu tava fazendo errado. Estou utilizando o VsCode como editor e instalei o plugin "Markdown Preview Enhanced". E é a partir daqui que vem a bizarrice: abrindo o preview no VsCode, as imagens estão perfeitamente alinhadas e as legendas estão devidamente centralizadas logo abaixo de cada imagem. Contudo, quando subi para o GitHub, as imagens ficam lado a lado, mas a legenda fica do lado direito de cada imagem.

#### O que tentei

Já fiz muitas "brincadeiras" com os espaçamentos e display no estilo. Inicialmente eu havia escrito uma tag "style" para poder deixar o arquivo mais organizado, mas descobri que o GitHub quebra essa tag no README por motivos de segurança. Aí passei o "style" como argumento das devidas tags (como podem ver no que anexei acima). Abri a ferramenta de desenvolvedor do meu browser (estou usando a versão mais atual do Chromium) e fui dar uma fuçada pra tentar entender e resolver o problema. Pude ver que foi adicionada uma tag "a" logo em seguida da tag "div", e isso não está na minha escrita original. Concluí que foi adicionado automaticamente um link que, ao clicar na imagem, leva para a pasta "src" que eu criei para guardar as imagens. Isso me leva a crer que pode ser por conta disso que as legendas foram "empurradas" para o lado direito das imagens. Tentei realçar as "caixas" para ver se eu entendia o que estava acontecendo e, ao realçá-las, me pareceu que foram criadas 4 caixas (uma para cada imagem e uma para cada legenda) lado a lado (o que me fritou a cabeça, sinceramente).
Portanto, quero saber se isso é um bug no GitHub (já que no Preview no VsCode parece estar normal) ou se há algo errado com o que eu fiz. Abaixo, anexo as imagens do Preview e do que aparece no README dentro do GitHub:

[image: Preview no VsCode]
[image: Como aparece no GitHub]

> Edit: se alguém quiser dar uma olhada no problema, é só acessar meu [GitHub](https://github.com/bryrrea).

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente o GitHub utiliza um renderizador de Markdown diferente do plugin que você utiliza no VSCode. Digo isso com base nesta discussão no próprio github: [clique aqui](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/529#issuecomment-123747741).

Fiz um fork do seu .md para tentar te ajudar, mas também não avancei muito. Encontrei estes 'snippets' sobre centralização de imagem em .md no github também caso queira:

- [Aligning images](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/7d2e0e1bc78f4ac59a123ddf8b74932d)

Comment: Gratidão pela resposta! Vou dar uma olhada no último link. Eu dei uma olhada mais cedo no tópico de discussão do próprio GitHub (o mesmo que você linkou). Novamente, gratidão pela ajuda! ^^